# Catch Exceptions inside a Message Driven Bean (MDB)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

How must I handle exceptions inside a mdb? I have the funny feeling that the exception happens after the try catch block so I'm not able to catch and log it. Glassfish v3 decides to repeat the whole message. It runns into a infinite loop and writes lot's of logfiles on the harddrive.

I'm using Glassfishv3.01 + Eclipselink 2.0.1

```
public class SaveAdMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="QIS") 
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                ObjectMessage obj = (ObjectMessage)message;
                AnalyzerResult alyzres = (AnalyzerResult)obj.getObject();
                save(alyzres);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) { 
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, e);
        }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    private void save(AnalyzerResult alyzres) throws PrdItemNotFoundException {

       Some s = em.find(Some.class, somepk);
       s.setSomeField("newvalue");

       // SQL Exception happens after leaving this method because of missing field for ex.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got a bad case of message poisoning...

The main issues I see are that:

- you are calling directly  the `save()` method in your `onMessage()`: this means thet the container has no way to inject the proper transaction handling proxy around the `save` method
- in any case the `save()` method should have  `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` in order to commit in a separate transaction, otherwise it will join the `onMessage` transaction (which default to `REQUIRED`) and bypass your exception handling code, beign committed after the successful execution of `onMessage`

What I woud do is:

Move the `save` method to a new Stateless session bean:

```
@Stateless
public class AnalyzerResultSaver
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="QIS") 
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void save(AnalyzerResult alyzres) throws PrdItemNotFoundException {
        Some s = em.find(Some.class, somepk);
        s.setSomeField("newvalue");
        // SQL Exception happens after leaving this method
    }
}
```

Inject this bean in your MDB:

```
public class SaveAdMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    @Inject  
    private AnalyzerResultSaver saver;

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                ObjectMessage obj = (ObjectMessage)message;
                AnalyzerResult alyzres = (AnalyzerResult)obj.getObject();
                saver.save(alyzres);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) { 
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Another tip: in this code the message poisoning still exists. Now it derives from the line invoking `mdc.setRollbackOnly();`.

I'd suggest here to log the exception and transfer the message to a poison queue, thus preventing the container to resubmit the message ad infinitum.

**UPDATE:**

A 'poison queue' or 'error queue' is simply a mean to guarantee that your (hopefully recoverable) discarded messages will not be completely lost. It is used heavily in integration scenarios, where the correctness of the message data is not guaranteed.

Setting up a poison queue implies defining a destination queue or topic and redeliver the 'bad' messages to this destination.

Periodically, an operator should inspect this queue (via a dedicated application) and either modify the messages and resubmit to the 'good' queue, or discard the message and ask for a resumbit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do i "tranfer the message to a poison queue"?

Comment: @HasanTuncay clarified the 'poison queue part'. I'm not sure that it is necessary in your case, since the poisoning derives from a 'programming' error. The log here should suffice, so simply omit `mdc.setRollbackOnly();`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the code that you have posted is mostly OK.

Your use of

```
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

is completely ignored because this (and most other) annotations can only be applied to business methods (including onMessage). That doesn't matter though because your onMessage method gets an implicit one for free.

This leads to the fact that message handling is transactional in a Java EE container. If the transaction fails for any reason the container is required to try and deliver the message again.

Now, your code is catching the exception from the save method, which is good. But then you're explicitly marking the transaction for rollback. This has the effect of telling the container that message delivery failed and that it should try again.

Therefore, if you remove:

```
    mdc.setRollbackOnly();
```

the container will stop trying to redeliver the message.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you're letting the container handle the transactions. This way, the entity manager will queue the operations that will be flushed after the method finishes, that's why you're having exceptions after the method is finished.

Using `em.flush()` directly as a final step in the method will execute all the related queries of the transaction, throwing the exceptions there instead of being thrown later when the `flush()` is made by the container while commiting the transaction.

Comment: Does flush() only commit the changes i made inside this one mdb or does it flush all kinds of transactions from other mdbs running at the same time. So what is the focus of the entitymanager when use flush?

Comment: And how do i stop the infinite loop?

Comment: the `flush()` method brings the actual persisting of the objects to the scope of the method (and the current transaction). By surrounding it with a `try-catch` block you should be able to catch the exceptions and handle them.

Comment: The message comes again and again from the queue. Somehow it seems like the rollback tells the queue that this message was not handled properly. I would like to put the exception into the log and remove the message from the queue or aknowlage it with "o.k. it's done"

Comment: Did you try doing that in the catch block?

Comment: yes, in the catch block i log the exception. But how do i tell the glassfish server that it should not send the message again and again? Even stopping and starting the server does not help. I start's sending the message again. :-(